# RaphaelJS drawing my SVG too far down the screen

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

My SVG keeps displaying too far down the page. 
I have carried out an exhaustive search over the past week and cannot find a solution.

please check here to see what I mean.

http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/raphael_map/

I can adjust the margin top by -450px but that will cause me problems later in the project. I followed the great tutorial on http://playground.mobily.pl/tutorials/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael.html to get as far as I did.

This is the SVG works.svg (tag this on to my link above to see, sOf limits me to two links. Might not work on your IE) I used for the map data in my raphael implementation.

Could anyone tell me why the SVG map is loading so far down the screen?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Tia.

(aside: the coat of arms displays on offline testing and just discovered it doesn't work online, minor issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strah is right: your paths are offset outside the window you intended for display.  Please DON'T recreate your paths -- it's just not necessary.  Simply transform your paths when you create them.  The coordinate system for complex, interrelated paths like this is already arbitrary; the relationships between paths are what is important, not the origin.

```
// init.js...

var obj = r.path(paths[county].path);

obj.attr(attributes).attr( { transform: "t0,-500" } );
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your paths.js says so.

For example if you take a definition of Donegal, copy and paste it into an online SVG editor like this one: [SVG-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html):

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path d="m249.813,525.80298c-1.31401,0.00403 -2.642,0.08698 -3.90401,0.08698c-2.552,0 -1.83499,1.54102 -0.28799,2.57202c1.73999,1.16003 3.37199,3.25903 4.86099,4.00403c0.64101,0.31995 2.688,3.70795 1.71501,4.29199c-2.804,1.68201 -3.63901,1.43799 -5.149,-0.57599c-2.48401,-3.31201 -0.968,-0.92303 -2.571,-0.28101c-1.15401,0.46198 -4.82501,0.263 -4.86101,0.28101c-1.505,0.75195 -3.717,1.18396 -3.717,3.72296c0,2.20099 -0.134,3.73602 0.85699,5.71899c0.664,1.32904 1.642,2.14502 2.284,3.42902c0.92101,1.84302 0.86301,3.474 0.86301,5.72498c0,1.98102 0.24699,4.073 -0.576,5.71802c-0.35199,0.703 -0.25499,5.28699 -0.856,5.43701c-1.23999,0.31 -5.14899,0.97699 -5.14899,2.57098c0,2.935 0.23299,2.83099 -1.71501,4.29199c-0.68399,0.513 -6.87199,3.12799 -5.19899,-0.21899c0.845,-1.68799 2.64999,-2.47101 3.14699,-4.461c0.466,-1.862 2.12001,-2.31799 2.634,-3.53497c0.183,-0.43103 -1.56,-0.94904 -1.38899,-1.633c0.53,-2.12201 1.563,-2.539 2.521,-4.45502c0.881,-1.76099 2.03799,-0.43701 1.433,-2.85901c-0.36,-1.44098 -0.895,-2.36096 -0.895,-4.15399c0,-1.83698 -0.84999,-5.07397 -2.82799,-5.56799c-2.681,-0.66998 -0.817,-2.19904 -1.714,-4.29199c-1.42101,-3.31403 -2.77299,-2.29004 -6.864,-2.29004c-1.793,0 -5.19701,0.54504 -5.769,2.828c-0.35201,1.409 -2.966,2.47205 -2.72801,3.90399c0.32701,1.96002 2.20201,1.33301 2.20201,3.27802c0,2.117 -1.37801,3.52802 -2.283,4.58002c-0.09599,-0.302 -1.96201,1.29297 -1.70799,-3.33398c0.101,-1.83502 0.06898,-2.86401 -4.34901,-3.03503c-1.286,-0.04901 1.731,-1.591 1.32001,-3.23401c-0.49699,-1.98895 -2.834,-1.521 -4.248,-0.81299c-1.437,0.71802 -0.60899,3.66901 -1.62,4.85504c-0.754,0.88397 -2.325,1.15497 -3.642,1.414c-1.47501,0.28998 1.21899,4.42596 -2.321,3.54095c-1.179,-0.29401 -0.99501,-1.03699 -2.12701,-2.32697c-0.823,-0.93805 -1.92499,1.48999 -3.23499,0.50696c-2.84201,-2.13196 -2.12001,0.50604 -4.248,0.50604c-0.789,0 -3.03401,-0.31201 -3.03401,0.80701c0,0.76599 0.39801,3.91699 1.01401,4.65497c1.646,1.97498 0.433,1.23798 -0.40601,3.03503c-0.847,1.81195 0.35001,3.65594 -0.30099,5.862c-1.235,1.05695 -1.877,-1.151 -2.73401,-2.427c-1.047,-1.55804 -0.56999,-0.86102 -2.52699,-0.90704c-2.427,-0.05798 -1.69499,4.43604 -3.13499,5.15503c-2.71901,1.35901 -0.606,1.05402 -0.606,3.64099c0,1.34998 3.84999,2.98999 3.44,3.23499c-1.06801,0.64099 -3.47801,0.625 -5.05501,1.414c-1.64299,0.82098 0.043,3.40204 1.214,3.841c0.539,0.20203 1.056,0.46698 1.614,0.60699c2.145,0.53601 2.05099,-0.68896 3.64101,-1.00702c1.99399,-0.39899 4.01599,-0.74799 2.83499,1.61401c-0.466,0.93103 -0.79399,3.45099 0.40001,4.04803c1.88399,0.94196 0.681,1.64197 0.20599,2.828c-0.47,1.17499 -1.576,1.909 -2.42799,0.20697c-0.63701,-1.27301 -2.552,-3.07098 -4.44801,-2.83398c-1.68999,0.211 -2.18999,1.21399 -3.642,1.21399c-1.459,0 -4.047,-0.80701 -3.84099,1.013c0.39999,3.54498 0.93599,1.92102 2.42099,3.03497c0.96201,0.72101 3.026,1.20001 3.84801,2.02106c0.358,0.35797 0.62599,1.58295 0,2.83398c-0.32701,0.65399 -2.269,3.79999 -3.44,2.62799c-1.177,-1.17603 -1.631,-1.82599 -3.235,-2.22803c-1.24901,-0.31299 -2.597,-2.828 -3.23399,-2.828c-1.27501,0 -3.35101,-0.41895 -3.84201,0.80701c-0.187,0.46704 -0.153,3.89099 -0.606,4.04199c-2.62599,0.875 -3.073,1.052 -4.855,2.83405c-1.459,1.45898 -1.104,-2.10303 -2.22701,-0.60699c-0.98999,1.31897 -2.05499,1.02698 -1.21399,2.42798c0.612,1.021 2.424,3.58698 3.44,3.841c0.99599,0.24902 1.49599,4.82098 2.42799,4.44897c3.37199,-1.349 2.869,1.64105 5.862,1.21301c4.60699,-0.65802 0.642,0.25903 2.834,0.80701c1.287,0.32202 2.687,-2.508 3.035,-2.42102c1.15599,0.289 1.888,3.69403 2.42099,2.62701c0.565,-1.13 3.50101,-3.40399 4.048,-1.21399c0.614,2.45502 -0.45799,1.35901 -2.021,3.23499c-0.496,0.59503 -1.978,2.99902 0,2.83398c1.89099,-0.15698 4.26399,0.31403 4.849,-2.02698c0.437,-1.745 1.08099,-3.492 1.42,-4.849c0.853,-3.409 4.534,-0.86401 4.448,-0.81299c-0.995,0.59698 -2.004,4.39697 -0.606,4.04797c1.679,-0.41998 2.19701,-2.42798 4.04201,-2.42798c1.319,0 1.953,-1.41699 3.034,-2.22699c0.188,-0.14203 4.203,-2.61499 4.655,-0.80701c0.089,0.35498 0.81801,3.53198 0.2,3.841c-2.48399,1.242 -2.784,2.31 -4.44899,3.64197c-1.776,1.42102 -1.82001,2.16504 -1.82001,4.24805c0,4.00098 -3.166,-0.74005 -2.021,3.841c0.278,1.11499 0.133,3.16699 -2.021,2.62799c-0.27,-0.06702 -0.543,-0.133 -0.813,-0.20001c-0.158,0.21198 -0.218,0.521 -0.287,0.81299c0.339,0.25403 0.327,0.245 1.076,0.80701c0.91,0.68298 4.00299,2.05402 4.86099,3.00299c1.507,-0.02002 2.511,-0.18896 3.14601,-0.71997c1.57799,-1.31403 4.80099,-0.44702 5.71899,-2.28302c0.752,-1.505 3.72301,-0.83099 3.72301,-3.435c0,-1.70599 -0.30801,-3.71399 1.42699,-4.29199c1.30901,-0.43604 2.923,-1.68604 4.57901,-0.85699c1.459,0.729 2.52499,1.43298 4.57399,1.43298c3.108,0 1.53601,-1.745 3.716,-2.28998c2.42,-0.60504 -0.125,-3.36902 1.146,-4.00403c0.12701,-0.06396 5.07701,-2.43097 5.28601,-2.44c-0.93001,-1.23596 1.09799,-3.09302 -1.563,-4.42297c-1.112,-0.55603 -1.90401,2.00195 -3.147,2.00195c-1.56999,0 1.63501,4.05603 -2.002,3.14703c-1.089,-0.27203 -1.354,-2.578 -4.004,-2.578c-2.603,0 -1.72099,-2.82001 -1.72099,-4.86102c0,-1.96497 -0.908,-1.48895 2.28999,-2.85895c2.342,-1.00403 -2.008,-4.00403 2.289,-4.00403c2.147,0 5.45,0.29401 6.576,0.57599c0.37599,0.09399 6.86299,1.40302 6.86299,-2.28998c0,-2.492 3.412,0.44397 3.72301,0.85699c1.35899,1.81201 2.002,-3.51202 2.002,-4.00403c0,-1.58099 -0.073,-3.15399 0.28099,-4.573c0.72301,-2.888 3.436,-1.33698 3.436,-4.57996c0,-2.28003 0.46201,-2.75305 2.002,-4.29205c0.55301,-0.55396 1.394,-1.76196 2.146,-3.00299c0.16501,-0.45099 0.832,-0.94196 0.714,-1.00098c-1.291,-0.64502 0.873,-4.28601 -0.569,-4.28601c-1.799,0 -2.106,-3.82397 -1.433,-5.14899c1.41,-2.77698 0.039,-3.716 3.716,-3.716c0.903,0 3.29399,-2.00201 3.435,-2.00201c2.386,0 4.892,0.56903 4.86099,-1.72101c0.033,-0.01001 0.09401,-0.021 0.15001,-0.03101c-0.42101,-0.29498 -0.716,-0.52295 -0.72,-0.53796c-0.502,-2.01001 0.047,-2.336 1.427,-3.716c0.96701,-0.96698 3.45801,-2.65002 4.42999,-3.62299c1.09,-1.09003 0.785,-2.50305 2.15201,-3.52899c1.28699,-0.96503 2.86301,-1.26404 4.573,-2.29004c1.37,-0.82202 4.267,0.13403 4.57999,-1.43298c0.45001,-2.25201 1.87701,-2.48401 1.427,-4.28601c-0.302,-1.20697 -0.39398,-3.91302 -2.28998,-4.29199c-2.15701,-0.43103 -3.62802,-1.43298 -6.28802,-1.43298c-2.03598,0 -2.569,-1.13 -3.72299,-2.57104c-0.72,-0.89996 -3.04599,-3.052 -3.42899,-3.14697c-2.36101,-0.591 -2.24301,-2.70703 -4.00401,-3.14703c-1.205,-0.30194 -2.504,-0.37494 -3.81799,-0.37097l0,0zm-24.364,87.16602c0.00301,0.00397 0.00301,0.00897 0.00601,0.01202c0.00899,-0.00702 0.00198,-0.01202 -0.00601,-0.01202z" id="svg_1" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I took a path definition from your script.

So, in the nutshell: re-create your graphic. You can use the above mentioned editor, but some laborous copy/paste will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I suspected that was the case but every time I loaded it into Inkscape it displayed it in the center of the worksheet.

Comment: I just redid all my coord data using your method. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Put your map defined by path into a set. This is easy, it's a line of code before you start creating paths and a line of code after the very last path you make.

You can see 2 identical sets being made here. They would lie on top of each other unless 1 was moved.

A picture paints a thousand words.
Here is the simple example and then you should know how to do this for ever...

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=movingpath